# LibreOffice Writer works very slow on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

I have libreoffice from base repo. Some time ago libreoffice writer started working very slow - for example I have to wait about 10 seconds to close the file. I created `newuser` on the same ubuntu and run libreoffice under new account - it works fine and very fast. So I deleted /home/olduser/.config/libreoffice - however it didn't help. What else can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general performance tweak I always enabled on all my machines where I use LibreOffice and on other machines to increate the general performance. It's hard to tell whether you have a different problem but you might as well give it a try.

In LibreOffice Writer, go to `Tools` and select `Options`. Click on `Memory` Increate the value of `Graphics Cache -> Use for LibreOffice`. Start with a value of `128 MB`. And `20 MB` for `Memory per Project`.

Accept with `OK` and restart.

It was a quick Tip I once found while surfing and it generally felt better and more responsive. I don't guarantee anything though.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help.

Comment: Don't you mean "Memory per Object" not "per Project"? I had terrible performance of e.g. scrolling with just a dozen of 320x240 pictures inserted.  The values were like 20 MB and 1,5 MB per object. It took off after this change, but then my document got corrupted (likely unrelated).

Comment: Do you know if that tweak sill works (2018, LO6) and with the same parameters?